# Active User and their related Tasks SOQL

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, tasks, user

I want to fetch the list of active `User` and their list of `Task` records.

**Following Query works for me to fetch all `Task` records with an active `User`**

```
select 
    Id,
    Subject, 
    Status, 
    OwnerId,
    Owner.Name,
    Owner.IsActive
from Task 
where OwnerId in (select Id from User where isActive = true)
```

Thanks to @BarCotter.

Now, I want `Total` and `Completed` counts of `Task` records for each `User` separately and print the results in `Visualforce`.

**Visualforce**

```
<table>
    <apex:repeat value={!listUser}>
       <tr><td>
          <input type="text" class="myJSClass" value="{!taskPercentage}"/> 
        </td></tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

**Apex Method**

```
public Double getTaskPercentage(){
    // *** HERE I want to calculate the Tasks Percentage like
    Double tpercent = (taskcompleted * 100)/totaltask;
    return tpercent;
}
```

I am thinking of using `apex:actionFunction` but I am little confused today with the basics.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where abouts are you stuck? Are you trying to do it all in SOQL?

Comment: I want List of all task for each user, Like Contacts of Account  i.e. Map<accountid, List<contact>>

Comment: You are going to need to take the results of your SOQL and build a list of inner class objects - where each object is for a single user and its Tasks. That inner class object can then have getter methods that do useful work - like % completion, totals, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Perform SOQL and create Map by results

Comment: updated question

Answer (score -1):

Using Wrapper Class I did solved my problem with very ease.

Comment: Can you please provide more details or an example of how you solved the problem?